# Do you need "name.html" for EasyXDM iFrame resizing?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, easyxdm

Does anyone know if you require the "name.html" easyxdm file when resizing a browser cross-domain, and if you do, where do you tell easyxdm to look for it?

I currently pull a booking form from another website in an iFrame, however I can't see any examples where the name.html is referenced, so I'm worried I haven't set it up correctly.

The page does appear to work though, I'd just like to make sure I have everything covered.

A demo of what I'm using is here: [Test page pulling data from dev site on another domain.](http://www.ultimatethailand.travel/test)

Here is my easyxdm code on the consuming website, should it perhaps be specified somehow in this javascript?

```
<div id="container" style="width: 100%;"><div id="loadingmsg" style="color:white; font-size: 12pt;">Loading...</div></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    new easyXDM.Socket({
        remote: "http://dev.ultimatetripstore.com/Book/Arrival-External?pid=1&SkinSrc=/portals/_default/skins/_default/no%20skin&ContainerSrc=/portals/_default/containers/_default/no%20container&bgcolor=000&fontcolor=fff&themecolor=d80c8c&hcolor=ffffff",
        swf: "http://dev.ultimatetripstore.com/easyxdm.swf",
        container: document.getElementById("container"),
        onMessage: function(message, origin){
            this.container.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].style.height = message + "px";
            this.container.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].style.width = "100%";
            this.container.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].frameborder = 0;
            this.container.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].style.border = "0px solid red";
            this.container.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].scrolling="no";
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the easyXDM.js file I found how to add the **name.html** file correctly.

This is assuming you already have the iFrame working to some degree.

**On the provider website**

1. Add **name.html** to the root of the directory
2. At the bottom of your providing page add the following snippet, make sure you include the **local** property and set it to the location of your name.html file.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var socket = new easyXDM.Socket({
       local: "name.html",
       onReady: function () {
       socket.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight);
       }
   });
   </script>
   ```

**On the consumer website**

1. Add the **remoteHelper** property to your existing javascript snippet and point it to the consumers **name.html** file. So in my case it was:

   ```
   <div id="container" style="width: 100%;"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   new easyXDM.Socket({
       remote: "http://dev.ultimatetripstore.com/Book/Arrival-External?pid=1&SkinSrc=/portals/_default/skins/_default/no%20skin&ContainerSrc=/portals/_default/containers/_default/no%20container&bgcolor=000&fontcolor=fff&themecolor=d80c8c&hcolor=ffffff",
       remoteHelper: "http://dev.ultimatetripstore.com/name.html",
       swf: "http://dev.ultimatetripstore.com/easyxdm.swf",
       container: document.getElementById("container"),
       onMessage: function(message, origin){
           this.container.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].style.height = message + "px";
           this.container.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].style.width = "100%";
           this.container.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].frameborder = 0;
           this.container.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].style.border = "0px solid red";
           this.container.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].scrolling="no";
       }
   });
   </script>
   ```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: there is so few people that have worked with easyXDM. May you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203172/easyxdm-download-files-from-3rd-party-service please?